# Select Query To Show Data From Friday To Thursday

Tags: sql-server-2008, date

My date field that this should be based off of is `shipdate` how can I run a `Select` statement and have it return data from Friday to Thursday without hard coding in dates?

Something like

```
Select * from shippinginfo where shipdate between 'Friday' and 'Thursday'
```

For a little clarity this is what I want to achieve
The where clause should be between Friday and Thursday of the previous week. So for example this week it would be 08/28/2015 - 09/03/2015 but next week it would be 09/04/2015 - 09/10/2015

Comment: The question doesn't make sense to me.  all days fall between 'Friday' and 'Thursday' as no period has been defined thus the where clause is moot... are you looking to for a specific week? or week of year or between specific days?  which Friday and which Thursday?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx gives you how to do this once the requirements are better defined.

Comment: @xQbert between Friday and Thursday of the previous week.  So for example this week it would be 08/28/2015 - 09/03/2015 but next week it would be 09/04/2015 - 09/10/2015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you always want to return the interval between last Friday and this Thursday you can use date functions like below.

This assumes that the week starts on Monday, if not you'll have to adjust it a bit.

```
select * from shippinginfo 
where shipdate between dateadd(day, -3, getdate()-datepart(DW, getdate())) 
                   and dateadd(day,  4, getdate()-datepart(DW, getdate()))
```

The logic is: take the current date and subtract the number of the weekday and then either subtract 3 to get last Friday or add 4 to get this Thursday.

I'm sure it can be improved, but it should give you an idea.

As xQbert correctly mentioned in a comment this might give incorrect results if your `shipdate` column is a datetime value (due to issues with the time component) and if so you shoudl either modify the logic or cast the shipdate to `date`.

Comment: may need to wrap each in `convert(date, getdate())` to eliminate time though.  Otherwise the dates may not include all desired records.  still a valid answer though :P

Comment: @xQbert Good point, I was lazy and only tested using `date` as type, but the time part would mess things up.

Answer (score 0):

For this atleast you have to provide the date which is friday(as computer doesn't know is it friday). and +6 to that date is thursday.

**For ex:-**

step 1 :- You passed the date :- 14/08/2015(FRI)

step 2 :- +6 in date :- 20/08/2015(THU)

NOTE :- Whatever u pass +6 days increment is done. So if u want friday as first then pass friday date.